# Not able to store cookie on ios device in ionic 3 app

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, ionic3, sails.js

I'm working on a ionic project and api made in nodejs with sails. Login api is uses the waterlock authentication and send the cookie in header that saved on machine and next time when i hit any other api it will authenticate me using that cookie.

Issue 1:- But i'm facing the issue on safari that safari does not allow me to save the cookie. for allow the cookie i need to change the safari settings after that it's working fine.

Issue 2:- As i said i'm working on ionic 3 app so i'm using tough-cookie in the app to handle the cookie thing and it's working fine on android and browser but it does not working in ios. it does not allow me to save the cookie.

Does anyone have the solution for this? Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

that is a known problem of the `wkwebview`, but there is a solution using the following [plugin](https://github.com/CWBudde/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inject-cookie), you can read more about this in the github thread.

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/22#issuecomment-398036017